# google Calendar API - typescript types

Tags: typescript, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

Does anybody know if the google Calendar API (npm googleapis pkg) for node.js (or browser) has types available that could be used in typescript.
Allowing a strongly typed approach in node or angular.

I could not find a @types/googleapis npm package.
Nor anything in the doc.

Any advise welcome.

Thanks in advance.

--
The documentation says it is natively supported, no need for separate package.
[Doc - section Typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis)
BUT, when I try, as stated in the doc

```
    import { google, calendar_v3 } from 'googleapis';
```

Typescript tells me : 
[ts] Module '"/home/me/myProject/functions/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index"' has no exported member 'calendar_v3'. [2305]

When I look in googleapis/build/src/index.d.ts I see GoogleApis, that point to ../apis where all the apis are, with a v3.d.ts file including the namespace

```
    * @namespace calendar
    * @type {Function}
    * @version v3
    * @variation v3
```

So, obviously, it is there, but I am missing something ... but what?
How can you use this library in typescript?
An example would be welcome.

Philippe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can absolutely use this library with TypeScript.  It's written in TypeScript!  Here's a basic example:

```js
import {google} from 'googleapis';
const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
```

That's the right way to get a reference to a particular subsection of the API :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The issue for me here is that google.calendar() does not accept auth to be of type JWT, which is needed when using service accounts.

Comment: Is there  a complete example how to initiate the Service? I'm stuck with the basics - first of all how to set the API-key. Next would be: how to initiate the whole communication...

Answer (score 9):

@justin-beckwith's answer is correct, but retrieving the types also deserves an example:

```
import { calendar_v3, google } from 'googleapis';
import { OAuth2Client, Credentials } from 'google-auth-library';
import Calendar = calendar_v3.Calendar;
import Schema$Event = calendar_v3.Schema$Event;

const auth: OAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(...);
const calendar: Calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
const schemaEvent: Schema$Event = (await calendar.events.get({ calendarId, eventId })).data;
```

Comment: The issue for me here is that google.calendar() does not accept auth to be of type JWT, which is needed when using service accounts.

Comment: Is there  a complete example how to initiate the Service? I'm stuck with the basics - first of all how to set the API-key. Next would be: how to initiate the whole communication...

Comment: This line doesn't compile when using import, only works with require
const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });

Google SDK and examples are a mess

Answer (score 0):

Try following this [Angular 6 – Google Drive Api v3 example](https://hintdesk.com/2018/08/24/angular-google-drive-api-example/), I tried this tutorial to integrate Google APIs to my angular app. It is not `@types/googleapis` but `@types/gapi`.

```
npm install --save @types/gapi
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
npm install --save @types/gapi.client.drive
```

Instead of `gapi.client.drive` you will call `gapi.client.calendar`.

Comment: Thank you droidBomb. As per [goole's documentation, the gapi lib is to be used for browser](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js). I'm looking for a server implementation on node.js. [Here the docs says to use googleapi](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs). Still your answer is interesting.

Comment: droidBomb, were you able to make this work? If so, can you put a Codepen or JSFiddle or such up for us? Thanks!

Comment: I am no recommend using the client on node.js and vis versa. But it is great if Client(Browser) manage to reach consensus so most stuff run on ES6/7 in near future.