# How can I type the OAuthClient from googleapis?

Tags: typescript, google-api

I am working on nodemailer app with gmail `OAuth2` in TypeScript, with `"noImplicitAny": true,"noImplicitReturns": true`. This requires me to explicitly specify return types.

I have this snippet

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export const getOAuth2Client = (): OAuth2Client => { // 2. So I set the return type as OAuth2Client  
  const { OAuth2 } = google.auth;

  const auth2Client = new OAuth2(
    process.env.G_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    process.env.G_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
    process.env.G_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL
  );

  auth2Client.setCredentials({
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/camelcase */
    refresh_token: process.env.G_OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN,
  });

  return auth2Client; // 1. Inspecting auth2Client shows its of type OAuth2Client
};
```

I got the `OAuth2Client` type on inspecting the type of the returned `auth2Client`. The problem though is where to import it from and use it in the project.

I tried the following...

```
import { google, OAuth2Client } from 'googleapis';
```

That fails as `googleapis` has no such named export.

I also saw this approach from [@corolla answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61163080/3758602) where he imports the types from `google-auth-library`

```
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';
```

I would wish to use the type without having to add another library as a dependency just for a single type for an already typed library (Much as `googleapis` uses types from `google-auth-library` under the hood, the project linter requires me to list it as a project dependency, which I wouldn't wish to do for now). Is there any other way I can go about this please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled with just disabling the `eslint` warning for `no-extraneous-dependencies`.

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';
import { google } from 'googleapis';
```

I couldn't specifically specify `google-auth-library` as a project dependency just to pick one type, yet under the hood, the `googleapis` package was also importing the types for the same package. So I wouldn't be breaking anything I guess.