# Angular: How to integrate Google Calendar API?

Tags: angular, google-api

I try to integrate the Google API into my Angular project. But somehow I fail with the basics :-/ What I did:

1. Install `npm install googleapis`
2. Using a sample code to get connected

I ussed the following sample code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare const gapi: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleCalendarService {
  private readonly CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
  private readonly API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
  private readonly DISCOVERY_DOCS = ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'];
  private readonly SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly';

  constructor() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: this.API_KEY,
        clientId: this.CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: this.DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: this.SCOPES
      }).then(() => {
        // Authentication successful
        console.log('auth success');
      },  (error: unknown) => {
        console.log('Google Error:', error);
        // Error occurred during authentication
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And here the problems start spinning. The API-Key I have retrieved. But do I need a specific Client_ID? I'm thinking this could be just an arbitrary ID.

The main problem is that I have no clue how to instance the basic authentication, i.e. how to get a proper instance of `gapi`?

NOTE: I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53306382/325868) but this doesn't help with a complete setup - especially since I have no clue how to set the API-key nor how initialize the communication.

Comment: I would create web app credentials for angular https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBVAyU4pZOU

Comment: The credentials are one part. I found a lot of tutorials. But how to integrate them finally into Angular? I have no clue how to use the Google libraries there. The approach I've tried, I've posted. But this doesn't work :-(