# Angular: Usage of Google Calender API

Tags: angular, google-api

A follow up of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77380238/325868). I tried to [follow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#typescript) and try to use some kind of this code:

```
import { google, Auth } from 'googleapis';
...
export class GoogleCalendarService{
  constructor() {
    //this.auth.setCredentials(new ())
    console.log('loginto Google1');
    const auth: Auth.GoogleAuth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth();
    const calendar = google.calendar({
      version: 'v3',
      auth,
    });
...
```

but this results in failures like:

```
./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js:7:11-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in '/home/lw/github/z-calendar/node_modules/jws/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }
```

1. Does this means that I haven't installed the package properly? If so, how to do it to get it working with Angular?
2. Where do I specify the credentials - especially the scope and the API-key?